# Compile cocos2d-x Windows games without Visual Studio

Tags: cocos2d-x, windows, visual-studio

I want to use cocos2d-x to make a Windows game. I used the cocos console:

```
cocos compile -p WIN32
```

And apparently it needs Visual Studio.

Is there an alternative to build the Windows game without Visual Studio? Anything more lightweight? I am hesitant to use Visual Studio because I actually work on many different machines and they all have somewhat limited memory.

Any other smaller IDE would do. Or even better, some sort of command line tool.

Comment: You do not actually have to fire up the IDE to compile with VS. Just run VSDIR\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat in your console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Qt Creator (with MinGW) to compile cocos2d-x on Windows, here's a step by step guide by Martell on the official forums:

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/setup-fastest-setup-for-cocos2d-x-on-windows-with-qt-creator-debugging/15177

Qt Creator/Qt is a Cross-Platform IDE and application framework. Download it here:

http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/

Comment: I'll take a look at it. But what if my game is commercial?

Comment: In this particular case, you just need the Qt Creator IDE to compile cocos2d-x,  so there's no issue in terms of commercial licensing.